# Generic he, correct or incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns, gender-neutral, singular-they, gender-politics

Completely ignoring the sexist aspect of the word, is using "he" as a gender neutral pronoun grammatically correct or incorrect? I'm well aware that using "he" may come off as sexist or politically incorrect and that it's better to use "they" but **grammatically** is it correct?

Comment: It depends on what school of grammar you adhere to. Some still don't count it as correct, especially the people who run the SAT--apparently "he or she" is the gender neutral reference in their questions. He is grammatically incorrect, to my knowledge.

Comment: Define "grammatically correct". No, this is not a joke; I'm perfectly serious. What does it mean? What is the test a sentence can be put to in order to ascertain this thing -- whatever you think "correct" means. I'm asking because I don't understand what you think this even means. It's an honest question and until you answer it, no meaningful response is possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cambridge Grammar, *he* was the sex-neutral pronoun for quite a while. However, eventually, when equality between women and men became prominent, the use of *he* became controversial because "[it] represents one of the most obvious and central cases of sexism in the English language..."

So people began using *he or she* instead of *he* as a sex-neutral coordination to avoid that sexist bias. But in informal conversation, it says, using it repeatedly can sound clumsy or clunky.

*They* as a sex-neutral pronoun with a singular antecedent actually dates back to Middle English. Some people use that as an argument for the use. Others argue that *they* is supposed to be plural, so it shouldn't be used as a singular, sex-neutral pronoun. But even still, *they* grows in use, and the book seems to accept it as the pronoun.

Of course, that leads to the obvious question of, "*Themselves* or *themself*?" It doesn't say that it's specifically **wrong**, just that it will gain further acceptance as the use of *they* becomes more common. And it's been thirteen years since the book was written, so I'd like to think it's quite a bit better accepted.

TL;DR: If you don't want to use *they* because people might object or you don't like *themself*, use *he or she*. I personally prefer *they*.

Comment: The traditionalist in me is pained to say this, but, if we will accept singular *you* along with *yourself*, then we may as well accept singular *they* along with *theirself*.

Comment: @Anonym The Grammar never mentions *theirself* as an option, actually. And for good reason--that would be silly. Do we say *hisself* or *theirselves*? No, certainly not. So we could reasonably exclude *theirself*.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit [re comment] Silly? Do we say _myself_ or _meself_?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit I meant to write *themself*, although I also have no objection to *theirself* or *hisself*, just as I have no objection to *myself, thyself, ourselves,* and *yourselves*. There seems to be something peculiar about the third person that makes the objective form more favourable, nevertheless.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I realised that too late--I could no longer edit.

Comment: @Anonym That's true. I wonder what etymologists have to say about that.

Comment: @Anonym And the traditionalist in you doesn't have to be pained. "They" has been used in the present context since Middle English, and surely they used "themself" or something similar.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit I did a quick search on Etymonline, and it seems that before about 15c. all the reflexive pronouns contained the dative (*meself, theeself*). It seems that some of them have been altered on the assumption that *self* is a noun (originally an adjective) and by influence of *herself*, whose first element is ambiguous case-wise.